# MongoDB PHP Driver on Zesle

Tags: php, xampp, php-mongodb

I can't find a way to install "MongoDB PHP" Driver as I am using "ZesleCP" for my web hosting as control panel.

Ubuntu 16.04.4 x64

Comment: How you tried to install it? Did you got a error?

Comment: @AngelDoza I don't even know where to begin with. I couldn't find any instructions online.